# How to link page like href="#page_3" in select option in intel xdk?

Tags: html, href

```
<select id="byplanname" name="byplanname" style="display:none;">
    <option value="Select Plan Name" multiple="multiple">Select Plan Name</option>
    <option value="815" href="#page_3">815</option>
    <option value="816">816</option>
    <option value="816">817</option>
    <option value="818">818</option>
    <option value="820">820</option>
    <option value="821">821</option>
    <option value="822">822</option>
    <option value="823">823</option>
    <option value="904">904</option>
</select>
```

The `href="#page_3"` is not working ,Please tell me proper linking in intel xdk..thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    <select id="byplanname" name="byplanname" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="google.com">815</option>
    <option value="google.com">816</option>
    <option value="google.com">817</option>
    <option value="google.com">818</option>
    <option value="google.com">820</option>
    <option value="google.com">821</option>
    <option value="google.com">822</option>
    <option value="google.com">823</option>
    <option value="google.com">904</option>
</select>
```

For using `#page_3` you will have to put in your URL before that so it would be `website.com/#page3` in the `value` field

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqB3Z/